# AS3 - accessing and editing loaded swf movieclip from main movie

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, movieclip

```
    import com.hydrotik.queueloader.*;
.................  

public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
 private var _ql:QueueLoader; 

private function _loadSTRATIntro()
            {
                QLog.log("_loadSTRATIntro()");
                this._ql.addItem("res/swf/STRATIntro.swf", this.introduction_mc);
                this._ql.addItem("res/swf/STRATTransitions.swf", this.transitions_mc);
                this._ql.addItem("res/swf/STRATDisOrDat.swf", this.STRATdod_mc);
                this._ql.addItem("res/swf/STRATMultipleChoice.swf", this.STRATMultiChoice_mc);
                this._ql.addItem("res/swf/STRATAttack.swf", this.stratattack_mc);
                this._ql.addEventListener(QueueLoaderEvent.QUEUE_COMPLETE, this._onQueueComplete);
                this._ql.addEventListener(QueueLoaderEvent.QUEUE_PROGRESS, this._onQueueProgress);
                this._ql.addEventListener(QueueLoaderEvent.QUEUE_START, this._onQueueStarted);
                this._ql.addEventListener(QueueLoaderEvent.ITEM_COMPLETE, this._onQueueItemComplete);
                this._ql.execute();         
                return;
            }// end function
```

I need to get access to loaded STRATTransitions.swf from the main movie and remove some text from it. There is no source code available for the swf. Is it possible to accomplish? Thank you in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

If they are both AS3 movies then I don't see why you can't access the corresponding textfields. If the text is in a dynamic textfield you can access it directly after loading the movie. If the text is static then you may be able to change it using the TextSnapshot class

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextSnapshot.html

Good Luck!